# How to display two values of two tables on chartkick (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, chartkick

I have column `vote_option` belong to `Vote` table and `title` in `VoteOption` table
and now I want to show `vote_option` and `title` in pair in a pie chart(chartkick). So what exactly should I do? I mean what should I do with this code: `<%= pie_chart Goal.group(:name).count %>` to show `vote_option` and `title` like value and key of a hash?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must
include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the
shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.
Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other
readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable
example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a table that references the data in the two tables?
For example you could combine the columns (reference by ID) from the two tables into a model table called Vote_title.

Then in your ruby code you could do something like the following:
In your controller (assuming this is on your index page):

```
def index
   @vote_titles = Vote_title.all
end
```

On your index page:

```
<%= pie_chart @vote_titles.group(:title).sum('vote_option') %>
```

In that example, the pie chart would display each title as a slice/percentage of 'vote_option' relative to the other title's vote_options. The legend on the side would list all titles and their colors. Reverse title, and vote_option in the erb code on your index page if you want the opposite.